# Replacing all html tags with newlines (or spaces)

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out how to replace all html tags with newlines.

I have a csv file with information in it, but I don't want the html. If I get the text instead of displaying the html the string returned is concatenated (using the example below it would return ActingDirectingIntroduction To ActingCollege WritingIntroductiong To Writing).

I would like to be able to be able to replace all html tags (anything inside of <...>) to be replaced with a newline character.  Any help would be appreciated, example below!

```
<ul>
<li>
 Acting
</li>
<li>
 Directing
</li>
<li>
 Introduction to Acting
</li>
<li>
 College Writing
</li>
<li>
 Introduction to Writing
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just call `soup.get_text()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using the excellent library `lxml.html`

```
import lxml.html
document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_string)
print(document.text_content())
```

And here are the relevant docs http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods

Comment: I also found this recently after posting and it works well . http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2010/09/truco-manso-eliminar-tags-html-en-python/